# number listing for conditions in sqlite

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a table in which I am trying to create a column that will increment based on conditions being valid.

In my example, I need to update the department count where the department = Marketing. Anyone have a good way to do this using SQLite?

Current Table

```
Name        Department     Department_Count
James       Accounting     NULL
Jennifer    Marketing      NULL
Micheal     Warehouse      NULL
Natalie     Marketing      NULL
Rebecca     Marketing      NULL
```

Update Table

```
Name        Department     Department_Count
James       Accounting     NULL
Jennifer    Marketing      1
Micheal     Warehouse      NULL
Natalie     Marketing      2
Rebecca     Marketing      3
```

Edit:

Currently, I insert rows where the department is 'Marketing' into a new table and then I used primary key or rowid to create an auto increment so I can number these types of items.

This requires me to create a new table which is not the best since it takes up so much space and the table is redundant since I have the underlying data in this original table already.

I'm using python to interact with my database, if that helps with solving this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I honestly don't have a clue if sqlite can even do what I'm asking. Currently I drop this into a new table and then use the rowid to give me an incremental value.  It's not a great solution since I have to create a whole new table to do this I'd really like to have this contained in a single table and just update the columns if it's possible to do in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Actually, thinking about it a little further, you may not need a trigger:

```
 INSERT INTO Table (Department, Department_Count) 
    VALUES (?, (SELECT MAX(IFNULL(Department_Count, 0)+1 FROM Table WHERE Department = ?))
```

may give you what you want.

**Original Answer**

You cannot do this declaratively, but you can probably accomplish what you want proceduraly using a [trigger](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html).

Two possible strategies:

1. Use an AFTER INSERT trigger to execute an UPDATE statement against the most recently inserted row (RowID will be available AFTER INSERT) to set the Departement_Count column to a SELECT expression based on the current data in the table.
2. Use an INSTEAD OF trigger to perform an alternate INSERT combining the values from the NEW cursor with a similar SELECT statement to get the maximum value (plus 1) from the Department_Count column.